# difference between freeswitch and red5

Tags: red5, freeswitch

Firstly I just want to know that what is the difference between freeSwitch and Red5?

As I have very good working experience with red5 and I have made many app's that streamed video/audio using Red5.

But now I am not able to understand that If Red5 can do video/audio conferencing or streamed live video then what is the use of FreeSwitch in conferencing or in other things.

I want to make a app in PHP or rails or Django(Python) where users can record their voice by participating in conference and while recording, the voice of all users will be broadcast to other members.

So now I really want to know what will be the right solution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

FreeSWITCH is primarily a telephony application server. So, it is oriented on solving the telephony tasks. There is also support for WebRTC, and some work is being done for video conferencing.

What you can easily do with FreeSWITCH, is allowing users join your Red5 conference from the telephony network.

Comment: I ask you this question because you seem to be very active in the Freeswitch vs. Asterisk debate. Do you know about the control structure (in terms of developers) of Freeswitch? Is it as broadbased as some of the Opensource development groups are? I just get a feeling that it is more-or-less a one man show (slightly extended). I know that on the face this appears to be a non-technical issue but I have seen software bloom in the opensource arena and then just die because THE key developer just abandoned it and went on to fork a commercial version or moved on to other things.

Comment: No, here they have several developers in the core team, plus a great industrial community that supports them financially. If Anthony decides to leave, there are people and companies which would support further development. But I don't see why he would need to quit.

Comment: I'm not in their development team, but looked into the code a few times. If needed, I would also be able to produce new features for FreeSWITCH. It's really a great product, and way better than Asterisk in many aspects.

Comment: On a different note, since you have looked at the source code, I saw in the book a whole chapter dedicated to Lua scripting while there is a mention of support for JavaScript. A quick look at it gave me an understanding that it only uses basic language constructs. If so, why introduce support for a whole new language when JS is so widely used and its basic language construct would have sufficed? Have you used JS scripting with Freeswitch? Stable? How about MySQL interface?  Sorry to bug you with these questions. Just a 1-liner would suffice and will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I only used Lua for a few small scripts. At the moment the external script (Lua or JS) is compiled at the time of execution, and Lua is much faster and light-weight, so more suitable for real-time applications. There's also the Event Socket interface where you can integrate with any programming language of your choice.